# How to access data inside if statement in Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

To the handlebars (version 1.0.0-rc.3) template I am passing two variables , one is the json and the other one is the string containing the current language on site.

```
self.template = template({ data: self.model, lang:self.lang });
```

Then inside the template file I have the following structure:

```
    {{#each data}} 
    //this is working
    {{../lang}}   
       {{#if this.title}}   
         {{this.desc}}
         //i've tried this
         {{../lang}}
         //and this
         {{lang}}
       {{/if}}  
    {{/each}}
```

...but I couldn't access the lang value inside the if statement. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find a solution by creating a handlebars helper function:

> Handlebars.registerHelper('language', function() {
>               return self.lang;             });

Then in the template i could use {{language}}
 where ever I want.

Comment: Check the solution I provided you to see if fits you better than registering a helper.

Answer (score 2):

I know you already solved your issue with a workaround but registering a **Helper** for doing a native way is cumbersome.

The thing is that every [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) helper overwrites the context and nest the new one inside the parent one, so you have to go up uone step further, like a **UNIX** like directory.

So, to access lang inside an `each->if` you have to use:

```
{{ ../../lang }}
```